# Apply same subset to multiple datasets in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I am pretty new to R, but I am working with several datasets containing the same data only from different days.

For my analysis I only need some specific columns from this dataset, therefore I created a new dataset with only the new colums (I do not want to overwrite or delete the old dataset). I am using the following code to do this:

> subset01012018 <- (dataset01012018[,c(1,2,3,4,10,11,14,15,16)])

Now I want to apply the same to all the datasets. How could I do something like this? Could I do this with a for loop? Or do I need an apply function?

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Just do `i1 <- c(1:4, 10:16); lapply(lst, function(x) x[i1,])`

Comment: @akrun should move the comma to the left, it's `x[,i1]` for columns :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Somehow I get an error message saying 'incorrect number of dimensions'. Do you maybe know how to solve this?

Comment: try `dim(x)` (when you're getting this error when doing something with `x`). `x[,1]` presumes x has exactly 2 dimensions (i.e. it is a matrix or data frame or 2-dimensional array) so it won't work if x has no dimensions (e.g is a vector or list) or has too many.